# AngularJS show login/logout button conditionally in navbar on app page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Main.jsp**

```
<html>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div class="navbar">
   <a href="/order"> View Orders </a>
   <a href="/logout" ng-show="$scope.isUserLoggedIn"> Logout </label>
   <a href="/login" ng-show="!$scope.isUserLoggedIn"> Login </label>    
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controllers**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
...    
            // route for the default home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : function($node, tattrs) {
                      return "resources/html/home.html";
                },
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })


            // route for the order page
            .when('/order', {
                templateUrl : function($node, tattrs) {
                      return "resources/html/order.html";
                },
                controller  : 'orderController'
            })
```

....

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
    ....
    $scope.isUserLoggedIn = true; //or false
.....
```

**Question:**
The $scope.isUserLoggedIn is having no effect on Login/Logout hrefs. The scope is probably not accessible on the main app page (i.e in the navbar in the ng-app page).

I want to show hide the Login/Logout button conditionally. Any ideas?

Comment: When configuring the route, you are assigning `mainController` to the `ng-view` div, that's why the navbar div can't use it.

Comment: hello Patrick> So where is ng-view assigned to mainController (as against any other) here.. At least not explicitly.. is it becz mainConroller is for "/" route?

Comment: ..when you are configuring the route.. `.when('/', { controller: 'mainController' }`. I just wanted to highlight that your code is almost complete, but the mainController is perhaps not available where you thought it was. That's why you need the ng-controller directive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing assigning `controller` to `div`

No need to use `$scope` there, just use

```
<div class="navbar" ng-controller="mainController">
   <a href="/order"> View Orders </a>
   <a href="/logout" ng-show="isUserLoggedIn"> Logout </label>
   <a href="/login" ng-show="!isUserLoggedIn"> Login </label>    
</div>
```

Comment: I was struggling a lot to do this and implemented so many things, probably this solution too.. but it worked for me this time!!!!!!